# SQL Server query syntax with single quote

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, escaping

I have in my database KIA car model like `CEE'D`.

How to write right syntax to get all car where model = `CEE'D`

Now I am using semipart of model

```
SELECT make, model 
FROM Cars 
WHERE model LIKE '%CEE%'
```

But now I need to get by full model name.

How to write right syntax in this case?

Comment: Use two single quotes: `WHERE model = 'CEE''D'

Comment: Heh just simple )) Thanks man. Make the answer I will accept as solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape a single quote (`'`) with another single quote - two in total (`''`). Note that this is **not** the double quote character (`"`), which is a single character, but **two** single quote characters (`'` and then another `'`):

```
SELECT make,model FROM Cars WHERE model = 'CEE''D'
```

Comment: Totally right. Just to be clear - this works on every stage. If you have a single quote in a quotation in a quotation this looks like: `SELECT '''''''''` -> '''' -> '